# Android Bluetooth maximum scanned devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

just wanted to know how many is the maximum number of bluetooth devices that at the same time (the same scan moment) a device can scan through android api. For instance, if you are in a concert, and there are hundred of bluetooth devices turned on (headsets, phones, etc), and i apply for a scan from my android device, how many of them i can scan (not connect and sdp discovery, because i know the maximum at a time are 7 in a piconet)? all?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what the Android API lets you do, but this is what you can do with the basic HCI for Bluetooth.

[How long does it take to scan for Bluetooth devices in range of an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837644/how-long-does-it-take-to-scan-for-bluetooth-devices-in-range-of-an-iphone/840059#840059)

Comment: i really appreciate your answer and time. as far as i understand this text, with hci you can scan all devices that are near the range of your device during 61 seconds, because on each inquiry time (1.28 sec), more than one device can answer. But, how is it for Android? i dont think so it should be different, right? it could be insane if they limit the number of devices you can scan in one time. But seeing what they did with time discovery, that they set to a max of 300sec ...

Comment: Looking at the android API for Discovery. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startDiscovery(), it indicates a standard Discovery takes about 12-seconds.

Comment: but even if its just 12 sec, as you described before, you can scan more than 1 device per 1.28 sec, right? i mean, that if they are giving you just 12 sec doesnt mean that you only can discover 12 devices,right?

Comment: thank you very much for your time and support. You clear all my doubts.