# How long does it take to discover a device with pyBluez?

Tags: python, bluetooth

I am considering using pyBluez, and my project requires quickly making a connection with a device.  How long is the acquisition time before data can be received from the device?

In this case the device will be a remote control, which will very frequently be taken out of range.  For bluetooth and pybluez to work for my application I need to be able to detect a button press on the remote within a few seconds of coming into range.  I have read [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/840059/480303).  Does pyBluez introduce other overhead, which makes constant discovery impractical?  After the device is discovered (minimum of 1.28 seconds I assume), is there any further delay before it can send data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong part of the Bluetooth protocol. 
You should be looking at connection times and client to server min-max times. Discovery is assumed over with, you only do that once to pair, right? Afterwards the remote control should know which device it controls, or the controlled device would recognize its paired remotes.

Later it is just about connecting with a client server model.

You need to decide the roles of each device. However, always trying to connect is not a good pattern even for a PC. You should be having on demand connections, which could take a few seconds(1-12 seconds, with the greater distribution somewhere in 0-5 seconds range).

We can discuss this further on chat, if you can give more specific details about your project.